# How to access my youtube channel with api using my google access token in ios?

Tags: objective-c, api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to make app based on youtube channel. I have google access token but I don't know how to call youtube api with my access token or how to pass parameters.

This is my code:

```
NSString *newURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"googleapis.com/youtube/v3/…;, idToken];
```

Comment: This is api that i am calling.. but getting error

Comment: NSString *newURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true&access_token=%@", idToken];

Comment: Please edit your post with more details and don't add them as comments.

Comment: and this is my skipe id : atpl.abhishek . you can talk to me on skype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in [Calling the YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Calling_a_Google_API), after obtaining an access token for a user, your application can use that token to submit authorized API requests on that user's behalf. The following are the two supported ways to specify an access token.

> 1. This first option provides greater security and is the recommended approach. Specify the access token as the value of the `Authorization: Bearer` HTTP request header:

```
`POST /feeds/api/users/default/uploads HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
...`
```

You can test this using cURL with the following command:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads
```

> 2. Specify the access token as the value of the `access_token` query parameter:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

You can test this using cURL with the following command:

```
curl gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: Thanks sir, but also one thing i want to know about access token .. how to get this token from youtube . any idea ??